# Try block is not catching a filesystem error

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have this fragment of code in a promise:

```
    try {
      const newFile = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
      response.pipe(newFile);
      newFile.on('finish', () => {
        newFile.close(resolve());
      });
    } catch (err) {
      reject(err);
    }
```

`response` is the result from `get` method in the `http` module, and
`filePath` is a string `/a/b/c/file.mp3/` where the folder `/a/b/c` does not exist.

Instead of the error being caught, the next line after this fragment is executed and it then crashes with:

> ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/a/b/c/file.mp3' at WriteStream.onerror ... at WriteStream.emit ... at lazyFs.open ... at FSReqWrap.oncomplete

Why is it behaving in this way?

The code works fine if `filePath` is a valid path.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`WritableStream` is asynchronous, and you can't catch its errors using `try...catch`. You should listen for an `error` event.

```
const newFile = fs.createWriteStream(filePath);
response.pipe(newFile);
newFile.on('finish', () => {
  newFile.close(resolve());
});
newFile.on('error', reject);
```

or more verbosely

```
newFile.on('error', exception => {
  reject(exception);
});
```